# Probability counting question - 30 balls in an urn

Tags: probability, combinatorics

An urn contains 30 balls: 10 red, 10 green, 10 yellow all balls from each color are labeled 1-10. What is the probability that you draw 3 balls that all have the same number. I tried (1 - the complement) but I'm having disputes on what exactly the complement case is mathematically. If you could help it would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

The first ball you draw can be anything. The second must be one of 2 (out of 29 available), the last must be 1 out of 28 available.

So the probability is $\frac{1}{406}$.

Answer (score 1):

There are $10$ groups of three balls that are OK, out of $\binom{30}{3}= 4060$ groups in all.

So the probability is $$\frac{10}{4060}=\frac{1}{406}$$